# Building an standalone jar to incorporate into an android project with scala sbt

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I have a scala project that I'd like to import into my android project as a library dependency. 
My thoughts are that this should be a standalone jar with the scala library and any other libraries included (i'm using monix for example).

I'm just not sure what tools to use to create this jar in a way that android can consume it (ie, making sure everything is compiled with java 7 and processed with proguard.)

Any insights or points in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

I found https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar but that didn't seem to work (after I added the generated jar, android seemed to not be able to find any of the actual classes).

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works.

I created Scala sbt project:

*build.sbt*

```
name := "scala_android"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"
```

*src/main/scala/mypackage/MyClass.scala*

```
package mypackage

class MyClass {
  def myMethod(): String = "AAA"
}
```

I did `sbt update`, `sbt compile`, `sbt package`.

Now I had jar `target/scala-2.11/scala_android_2.11-0.1.jar`.

Then I created Android project with "Empty Activity".

I put `scala_android_2.11-0.1.jar` to `app/libs`.

I wrote in `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile name: 'scala_android_2.11-0.1'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.11'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

and in `app/src/main/java/example/com/myapplication/MainActivity.java`

```
package example.com.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import mypackage.MyClass;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        Log.e("tag", obj.myMethod());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

refreshed Gradle project, started emulator and ran MainActivity.

Android monitor showed on error level

```
09-03 08:47:06.447 6549-6549/? E/tag: AAA
```

So it seems to work (surely at least in such "hello world" example).

Comment: I was able to do basically this^. I just had to make sure that the jdk I was using was java 7 when executing sbt (which, for me, the easiest way I found to do this was setting it through intellij). Also, sbt-assembly seems to work great for my standalone requirement, and I'm hoping that using proguard on the android side will work out so I don't need to deal with that atm.